# Error with in-memory H2 database Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I am trying to learn Java Springboot microservices and I have created a loan microsevices which uses in memory H2 database and it is giving error with the details`2023-10-12T12:26:55.058+05:30  WARN 4228 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL)`

I have already tried adding `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"` and also the delay option but it is still not working

```
application.yml file
```

```
server:
  port: 8090
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: ''
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
```

Answer (score 0):

**ADD SPRING-BOOT-STARTER-WEB DEPENDENCY**

In my case I forgot added spring-boot-starter-web as dependency in pom.xml.

The problem was solved after adding the following code to the pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```